# Setting up binary replication between two PostgreSQL instances

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.2

I have two virtual machines: `dbrepa` (`-.175`) and `dbrepb` (`-.191`).
Both have PostgreSQL 9.2 installed; once PG was installed (never initialized) on `dbrepa`, `dbrepb` was made as a clone.
I need to have the databases on `dbrepb` be read-only copies of those on `dbrepa`.

And so, I set the [appropriate settings](http://wiki.postgresql.org/index.php?title=Binary_Replication_Tutorial#Binary_Replication_in_6_Steps) of `dbrepa/postgresql.conf`:

```sh
listen_address = '*'
wal_level = hot_standby
max_wal_senders = 3 # Aside, I assume '3' is arbitrary
```

and `dbrepa/pg_hba.conf` (paying attention to spacing):

```
host   replication   all   192.168.108.191/32   trust
```

and `dbrepb/postgresql.conf`:

```
hot_standby = on
```

and `dbrepb/recovery.conf` (a new file):

```sh
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=192.168.108.175'
```

Each database is empty, but the following command was run on both:

```sh
[root@dbrep-]# service postgresql-9.2 initdb
```

---

Now, since there are no databases, I don't need to worry if they are out of sync (since there is no data to be out of sync).
I start the master:

```sh
[root@dbrepa]# service postgresql-9.2 start
Starting postregsql-9.2 service:   [  OK  ]
```

and I start the standby:

```sh
[root@dbrepb]# service postgresql-9.2 start
Starting postregsql-9.2 service:   [FAILED]
```

Examining the log files of each:

`dbrepa/data/pg_log/-.log` is empty.

`dbrepb/data/pg_log/-.log`:

```
LOG:  entering standby mode
WARNING:  WAL was generated with wal_level=minimal, data may be missing
HINT:  This happens if you temporarily set wal_level=minimal without taking a new base backup.
FATAL:  hot standby is not possible because wal_level was not set to "hot_standby" on the master server
HINT:  Either set wal_level to "hot_standby" on the master, or turn off hot_standby here.
LOG:  startup process (PID 4320) exited with exit code 1
LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

but when I double-check `dbrepa/data/postgres.conf`, `wal_level` is *clearly* set to `hot_standby`.

What else could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your last two steps are in the wrong order.

The [appropriate steps](http://wiki.postgresql.org/index.php?title=Binary_Replication_Tutorial#Binary_Replication_in_6_Steps) says

> - _ 5. Start the standby first, so that they can't get out of sync. (Messages will be logged about not being able to connect to the
>     primary server, that's OK.)
> - _6. Start the master.

You are supposed to start the master after the standby.

Try reversing everything as follows:

- `[root@dbrepa]# service postgresql-9.2 stop`
- `[root@dbrepb]# service postgresql-9.2 stop`
- rsync everything from Master (except the pg_xlog and config files ([Your Step 4](http://wiki.postgresql.org/index.php?title=Binary_Replication_Tutorial#Binary_Replication_in_6_Steps))) to Standby
- `[root@dbrepb]# service postgresql-9.2 start`
- `[root@dbrepa]# service postgresql-9.2 start`

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I'll try, but I did this the first few times I've gone through this. I'll let you know. **Edit:** Same result.  `dbrepb` fails while `dbrepa` succeeds.

Comment: Your link says when starting the standby first: `Messages will be logged about not being able to connect to the primary server, that's OK.`

Comment: Then why is the service start failing?

Comment: It's probably the logs in pg_xlog. Try shutting down again, rsync evening INCLUDING pg_xlog, and try it again. `DISCLAIMER: I am not a PostgreSQL admin`. Hopefully, someone with the proper expertise will eventually chime in.

Comment: According to http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Hot_Standby, it is suggested to use `pg_basebackup` to copy stuff to the standby. Try that instead of an rsync.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I think I just found an answer. If you modify the sample config (`initdb -D /tmp/foo -s | grep POSTGRESQL_CONF_SAMPLE`) and set `wal_level=hot_standby` in the sample config, then the base and WAL files will be created appropriately and Postgres will start and try to connect to the master DB.

I haven't figured out how to pass this to `initdb` directly yet.  I've tried `PGOPTIONS="-c wal_level=hot_standby"` and many similar invocations without success. YMMV.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to DB.SE! Thanks for the info.  Unfortunately, I very much don't have the test environment anymore, so I can't truly give a tick unless your question would be *exactly* the same as mine (same commands, same output, same everything) so I'm hesitant to do so. As for the last paragraph, your best bet is to ask a new question and provide a link back to this one.  Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks. I'll let others who stumble on this provide feedback. Cheers.